# AdMob Rewarded video ad return to view

Tags: ios, swift, admob

What happens when rewarded video ad start and then stop playing? 
I have a viewcontroller and an ARSCNView on it.
Everything works fine until rewarded ad stop playing.
After playing video i can't add any objects to the scene, functions work but nothing happens.

```
func rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
        print("Reward based video ad is closed.")
        //addPaddle()
        //new_iteration(iteration: iteration)
    }
```

Im trying to use video ad like that: you play game, when you fail you get a proposal to watch ad for instant continue playing, after watching ad you continue from fail moment.
What is wrong in my using of rewarded video ad?